# How to "mask" certain ArrayList elements from showing in a for (X : X) loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to create a Java class, extending ArrayList, which basically fills the list capacity with null elements upon creation, so when I add a new element to it, it doesn't actually creates it, it simply sets an already existing null to the desired value. Here is my constructor:

```
NullArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super(listSize = initialCapacity);
    for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) super.add(null);
}
```

The thing is when I put the list through a `for(X : X)` loop, it access all the null elements which I dont care about (yet). Of course I know I could just insert `if (x != null)` but I would like anybody to be able to use my class without always having to put an if statement in the loop (that would be a major design flaw).

So I was wondering if there wasn't anyway, maybe with an Iterator(?), to change the behaviour of the for each loop so that it skips the elements I want it to skip.

Comment: I think you are reimplementing the wheel. ArrayList<Integer>(10) will create 10 empty elements in a list. As for your answer: yes, you need to implement an Iterator and add it to your custome list.

Comment: Why do you want to create Null ArrayList? You can provide the capacity during the ArrayList initialization and it will reserve the memory for exact number of elements: new ArrayList(5); Iterator will work fine in that case as well.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your class offers nothing that is not already provided by `ArrayList` itself.

Comment: The thing is, in Array list, we cannot (to my knowledge) control the places of the empty elements. I am trying to have that control to test sorting and placing algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to modify the behavior of the `for` loop according to your requirements is by overloading the `iterator()` method and providing an `Ìterator`that skips null values. However, if you do that you will break the contract of the `Collection` / `List` interfaces and risk huge problems in the future.

Thus, the really sensible way to handle this is to add `if (value != null)` in your `for` loops.